# How can I estimate a Durbin Probit model (SDM) in R?

Tags: r, regression, spatial

I've been searching for code examples and documentation to run a Durbin Probit Model (SDM) in R, but haven't had much luck.

Currently, I'm using the ProbitSpatial package to fit a Spatial Autoregressive (SAR) Probit model using cross-sectional data with the following code:

model <- ProbitSpatialFit(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4,
W = W, data = model_data, DGP = 'SAR', method = "conditional", varcov = "varcov")

This code works well for the SAR model, but I'd like to modify it to estimate an SDM Probit model. Unfortunately, simply changing DGP = 'SDM' doesn't work.

Would anyone be able to help me with this? I've already explored various online resources, so any specific guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Please properly format the code. It should be a code block